# Definitions of differential forms in different coordiante systems

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, differential-forms, tensors, exterior-algebra

A p-form has the definition:
$$ \mathbf{\omega} =\omega_{|i_1...i_p|} \mathbf{d}x^{i_1} \wedge...\wedge \mathbf{d}x^{i_p} \tag{1}$$
Suppose a 2-form in Cartesian coordinates takes the form 
$$\mathbf{^*F}=E_{x} \mathbf{d}y \wedge \mathbf{d}z \tag{2}$$
Then its corresponding components in spherical coordinates are
$$\mathbf{^*F}=E_{r} (r\mathbf{d} \theta) \wedge (rsin\theta\mathbf{d} \phi) \tag{3}$$
But I do not see why the $r$ and $rsin \theta$ factors are needed here, shouldn't (2) simply be 
$$\mathbf{^*F}=E_{r}  \tag{4}$$
because all these "additional angular variable factors" for transforming from rectangular coordinates to spherical coordinates have already been taken into account by the definition of $E_r$ alone?

If $(3)$ is the correct definition then shouldn't $(1)$ be
$$\mathbf{\omega} =\omega_{|i_1...i_p|} (\sqrt{|g_{i_1i_1}|}\mathbf{d}x^{i_1}) \wedge...\wedge (\sqrt{|g_{i_pi_p}|}\mathbf{d}x^{i_p}) \tag{5}$$
(where $g_{kn}$ is the metric tensor)

instead?

In other words is a 2-form whose components are described using spherical coordinates defined as, e.g.(with all other components=$0$)
$$\omega= \omega_{23} (x^1\mathbf{d} x^2) \wedge (x^1sinx^2\mathbf{d} x^3)$$
where $x^1=r, x^2=\theta, x^3=\phi $?

Comment: In order to clarify, what does $E_x$ mean in $(2)$ and $E_r$ mean in $(3)$?

Comment: @Michael Albanese $E_x$ and $E_r$ mean the component of the same electric field along the x direction and radial direction respectively, whose definition don't matter very much in this question I believe. You could ignore $(2)$ completely. $E_{r}=\frac{e}{r^2}$ where e is some constant and r is the radial distance from the origin.

Comment: @Michael Albanese Please see edits.

Comment: My question is (and maybe also @MichaelAlbanese 's) when you ask "shouldn't (2) be ... by the definition of $E_r$ alone", what do you mean by the definition of $E_r$ here, as a component of a 2-form? If $E_r$ is as in (1) defined to just be whatever number comes in front of the $d\theta\wedge d\phi$ term, then I agree with you that it should just be $F = E_r d\theta\wedge d\phi$. But you seem to get (3) from some source, in which case maybe this is the defining property of $E_r$ (which maybe is your $E_r$ divided by a factor of $r^2\sin(\theta)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not coming from a change of coordinates from the $xyz$ coordinates to spherical. They're writing the orthonormal basis for the $1$-forms in spherical coordinates as
$$dr, r\,d\theta, \quad\text{and}\quad r\sin\theta\,d\phi.$$
(For example, the Euclidean metric in spherical coordinates is given by the $2$-tensor
$$dr\otimes dr + r^2\,d\theta\otimes d\theta + (r\sin\theta)^2\,d\phi\otimes d\phi.$$
We then read off the orthonormal basis from this.)

Remember that to compute the Hodge star, it is easiest to compute with an orthonormal coframe. So if $\mathbf F = E_x\,dx + E_y\,dy + E_z\,dz$, then $\star\mathbf F = E_x\,dy\wedge dz+ \dots$. Now in spherical coordinates, they're writing $\mathbf F = F_r\,dr + F_\theta(r\,d\theta) + F_\phi(r\sin\theta\,d\phi)$, and then they're applying $\star$ to this. In particular, $\star dr = (r\,d\theta)\wedge (r\sin\theta\,d\phi)$.

Comment: Does that imply $\mathbf{d}x^1=\mathbf{d}r, \mathbf{d}x^2=r\mathbf{d}\theta$ and $\mathbf{d}x^3=rsin\theta \mathbf{d}\phi$ if I've correctly understood your explanation? I find this strange because I thought all the bases should contain only one variable like $\mathbf{d}x^1=\mathbf{d}r, \mathbf{d}x^2=\mathbf{d}\theta$ and $\mathbf{d}x^3=\mathbf{d}\phi$?

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that $\bf{F}^*$ is a 2-form in 4-dimensions, so $\bf{F}$ would also be a 2-form, and in $(3)$ $E_r$= $^*F_{23}$.